# NDK issue in Android Studio Canary 3.0

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk

In my Telegram project, I am facing this issue. I have tried following:

1. ndk-build V=1 in project jni directory
2. Clean Project and Delete all intermediates
   None helped. Logs of NDK error. Please help!

https://pastebin.com/Fdb5VaXs

```
It contains the log for the same.
```

Comment: so in 2.3 / 2.4 it worked ok?

Comment: Yes. In Android Studio 2.3 latest Stable, its working perfect. Its some issue of Canary 3.0

Comment: so use stable, using canary you take a risk

Comment: I am forced now to use stable. I wanted to use latest features of 3.0 :(

Comment: you have to wait a little bit then...

Comment: ok. Thats sad though.

Comment: @pskink: That's bad advice. The case here is a bug in breakpad. Ignoring it until 3.0 (actually NDK r15) reached stable wouldn't have made the bug go away, it would have just taken longer to get the problem fixed. If you find bugs and don't report them, they'll still be present in the release. Also, in this case there's a workaround, so no reason to revert.

Comment: please give the link to that workaround @DanAlbert . I will miss 3.0

Comment: @DanAlbert good to know someone is keeping an eye on that ;-)

Comment: @OmkarNathSingh: see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like breakpad is not yet compatible with the new headers in the NDK. I've filed a bug with them to get that fixed: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/google-breakpad/issues/detail?id=733

Until then, you can revert to the old headers by adding `APP_DEPRECATED_HEADERS := true` to your Application.mk as described by [our docs](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ndk-r15-release/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md) that are linked in [the r15 beta 2 changelog](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r15-beta2).

Comment: Thanks. It worked as of now. Expecting NDK fixes soon.

Comment: Another Quick around is : Don't update NDK inside Canary. Let it remain the same as of old stable one.

Comment: Been so long, still no fixes.

Comment: I'll try to track down a breakpad maintainer. AFAICT no one has looked at the bug I filed yet.